# Advanced Forum Error When Posting

Tags: nodes

I have updated today to the latest version of Advanced Forum and when trying to post a new topic got the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '329-node' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {ip_posts} (type, id, ip) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 329 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 38932973 ) in ip_posts_insert() (line 162 of /home/thanatos/public_html/sites/all/modules/ip-7.x-1.4/ip/ip.module).
```

Could this be related to php timeout? I'm asking this because I took quite a while typing the Topic before posting it, because I was working it in HTML in Dreamweaver. However when I went back and created a new topic and posted it instantly, I had no issues.

Thanks in advance.

Miguel

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with the Advanced Forum module, the error is coming from the [IP address manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip) module. From it's error message, it looks like it's trying to insert a record that already exists. It could be a problem with how you upgraded that module (your dir suggests its version 1.4, but the line number matches [the latest 2.0-beta](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ip/tree/ip.module?h=7.x-2.0-beta1#n162)) or it could be a bug.

Either way, if you're not concerned with preserving historical data in the module, uninstalling, removing, and reinstalling the IP address manager module would be one way to get rid of the error.